# I get a error 400 when signing in with the google sign-in button on my webpage

Tags: google-signin

I am trying to put a google+ sign-in button on my website, but I get a 400 error when I try to sign in with it. this is all I get.

```
400. That’s an error.

The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.the
```

I have the following included in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="620096179377-ula3qjt2s01qqhberlqq470n16kccnh5.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

and the following where i wanted the button:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Google Login</title>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="620096179377-ula3qjt2s01qqhberlqq470n16kccnh5.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log(googleUser);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" 
   data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the issue persists, could you attach details for request that causes 400? (url should be enough)

Comment: I tested your code. im still getting the same error. here is the url        https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2F127.0.0.1%3A51792%3Fid%3Dauth48337&response_type=permission&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm=&client_id=620096179377-ula3qjt2s01qqhberlqq470n16kccnh5.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A51792&fetch_basic_profile=true

Comment: The error is: "Not a valid domain name: '127.0.0.1'". Can you switch to http://localhost?